# How can I fix my C# for-loop implementation of sorting in descending order that fails to iterate until the last element?

Tags: c#, sorting, for-loop, iteration

Write a method that finds the biggest element of an array. Use that method to implement sorting in descending order.

```
    static int FindBiggestElementIndex(int position, int[] arr)
    {
        
        int max = int.MinValue;
        for (int i = position; i < arr.Length-1; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > max)
            {
                max = i;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    static int[] SortDescending(int[] arr)
    {
        int tempnum = 0;
        
        for(int i=0; i<arr.Length; i++)
        {

            tempnum = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[FindBiggestElementIndex(i, arr)];
            arr[FindBiggestElementIndex(i, arr)] = tempnum;

        }
        return arr;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 5, 4, 34, 6 };
        foreach (int element in SortDescending(arr))
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", element);
        }
    }
```

I was expecting the results to be: 34,6,5,4,1 but instead I get 6,34,5,4,1
I do not understand why on the second iteration of for(int i=0; i<arr.Length; i++) the loop inside the FindBiggestElementIndex() only iterates until it reaches 3 instead of 4 while I clearly instructed it to go  from 0 till 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max index determination is wrong, you are comparing the array element with the index.

Using your approach, the first method should look something like this:

```
static int FindBiggestElementIndex(int[] arr, int p)
{
    int maxIndex = p;
    for (int i = p + 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > arr[maxIndex])
        {
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return maxIndex;
}
```

Second method:

```
static int[] SortDescending(int[] arr)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        int biggestElementIndex = FindBiggestElementIndex(arr, i);
        int tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[biggestElementIndex];
        arr[biggestElementIndex] = tmp;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Nitpicking 1:  - _not really relevant for the answer_ - I'd check `p` for < 0 _in production code_ ... Nitpicking 2: if `biggestElementIndex == i` you don't need the swap.

Comment: @Fildor thanks, I don't have much time to optimize the code further, so your comment will help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

`FindBiggestElementIndex` is wrong:

You save the index of the max you found and then compare it to the value.

You should compare it *to the value* at the max index.

```
static int FindBiggestElementIndex(int position, int[] arr)
{
    
    int max = position;
    for (int i = position; i < arr.Length-1; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > arr[max])
        {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: initializing `max` with `int.MinValue` may (probably will) result in ArrayIndexOutOfBounds.

Comment: ^^ Which is a detail, but _"You save the index of the max you found and then compare it to the value. You should compare it to the value at the max index."_ is still true, btw. So, maybe fix that @Tagada and people will reconsider their dv (I didn't dv).

Comment: true, didnt think enought ^^
I've edited my answer to init max to position instead, this should do the trick